# Xamarin Forms - subclassing MultiPage

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to create a simple subclass of Xamarin.Forms.MultiPage?

In code below I have a multipage that creates three simple pages (just labels and buttons on each) and then sets the current page to the first one defined.
However the call to set `CurrentPage` does not change what gets displayed on the screen. The displayed page is always the last one I added to `ItemsSource`.

Here is my code

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NavigationTrial
{
    public class CustomMultiPage : MultiPage<Page>
    {
        public CustomMultiPage () : base()
        {
            var children = new List<Page>() { 
                new SimpleOnePage(), new SimpleTwoPage(), new SimpleThreePage() } ;

            this.ItemsSource = children;
            this.CurrentPage = this.Children[1];
        }

        override protected Page CreateDefault (object item) {
            return (Page)item ;
        }

    }
}
```

I guess I'm missing something, but I wasn't able to find any examples that would clear this up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed that setting CurrentPage has no effects with MultiPage (whereas it has with TabbedPage).
So I went with setting IsVisible to true for the child I want to see and false for the other children. You can even bind it with SelectedItem and a converter.

I find it simpler than the previous answer with Layout. Especially for a windows desktop app as you can resize the window and see the "hidden" pages.

Comment: Clever idea. I simply didn't realize all pages are drawn on the screen and the last drawn one overlaps previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse it does that, it's how the multipage works.

What you're doing is simply stacking layout upon layout upon layout, changing which one is the "currentpage" while they're all already on the screen isn't going to do much.
If you're set on doing it that way then you'll have to manage their layouts manually.

Basically, change the layouts of the pages you don't wish to see so they're out of the way.
Something like this:

```
private Rectangle GetPageClosedRectangle()
{
    return new Rectangle(Width, 0, Width, Height);   
}

private Rectangle GetPageOpenedRectangle()
{
    return new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
}
```

And then swap out the pages whenever you want to hide/show one:

```
PageIDontWantToSee.LayoutTo(getPageClosedRectangle());
PageIWantToSee.LayoutTo(getPageOpenedRectangle());
```

the "LayoutTo" method is an async method, it animates the layout to the set rectangle. If you want it instantly you can use `page.Layout(Rectangle)`

Comment: I see, I didn't realize pages were kept in a stack that's drawn on screen, so that the one on top is always visible.